# Rails: Model limited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Hello I have a relationchip between Person and City. One City can has many People.

I want a City has maximum ten people?
how can i contrained that?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611887/calling-custom-validation-methods-in-rails where custom validations can be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the model code:

```
class Person
  belongs_to :city
end

class City
  has_many :persons
  validate_on_create :check_populations

  def check_populations
    return if persons.length > 10
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom validator inside your model. Have a looks here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2263294/1321564